# Magento create nested categories programmatically and recursivelly

Tags: magento, zend-framework

is there a way to create a nested categories using a string like:

```
Category 1/Category 2/Category 3/Category 4/
```

a such of method that help me to create them in easy way.

I have the base method:

```
public function createCategories($categories, $parentId=2){

    $arrcategories = explode("/", $categories);

    foreach($arrcategories as $category){
        $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
        $category->setName($category);
        $category->setIsActive(1);
        $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
        $category->setIsAnchor(0);

        $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());              

        $category->save();
    }
}
```

but how to create the recursively function?

I have grouped them in this array:

```
array(2) {
  [1] => array(3) {
    [0] => string(9) "PING PONG"
    [1] => string(19) "ACCESSORI PING PONG"
    [2] => string(13) "RACCHETTE NERE"
  }
  [2] => array(3) {
    [0] => string(9) "PING PONG"
    [1] => string(21) "PING PONG ACCESSORIES"
    [2] => string(11) "BLACK RACKETS"
  }
}
```

**The ID 1 and 2 are the store views id.**

thanks